# How to fetch all data from embedded documents only in a mongodb schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

There are two Schemas: User Schema and Book schema. There are n users and can have any number of books. I now have to fetch all the books existing in the database. I'm unable to sort out any solution for that. I have tried using populate but it isn't working. What can be the best approach for this kind problem. I dont want any data of User Schema, only bookList of every user.

Here is the userSchema.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Book = require('./book');

var userSchema={
    profile:{
        // Some more fields.
    },
    bookList:[Book.bookSchema] //Interested here
};

module.exports = new mongoose.Schema(userSchema);
module.exports.userSchema = userSchema;
```

Here is bookSchema

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

```
var bookSchema = {
    __id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    info:{
        //Some fields.
    }
}

module.exports = new mongoose.Schema(bookSchema);
module.exports.bookSchema = bookSchema;
```

The model.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var _ = require('underscore');
var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');
module.exports = function(wagner){
//Some codes
    var Book = mongoose.model('Book', require('./book'), 'books');
    var User = mongoose.model('User', require('./user'), 'users');
    var models = {
            Book:Book,
            User:User
    }
    _.each(models, function(value, key) {
        wagner.factory(key, function() {
          return value;
        });
    });
    return models;
}
```

Can I get any help in here? I've been stuck for hours!

Answer (score 0):

I tried using

```
api.get('/universe/book', wagner.invoke(function(User, Book) {// done
        return function(req, res) {
            User.find({},{profile:0, _id:0}, function(err, data){
                res.json({data:data});
            })
        };
    }));
```

and it works now.